# ELK tagging and type not filter syslog

Tags: elastic-stack

**ELK stack version**

- Logstash: 5.1.2
- Kibana: 5.1.2
- Elasticsearch:5.1.2

I have the below logstash configuration to send my router syslog events to elastic search. 
My router is configured to send events to port 5514 and I can see the logs in Kibana.

BUT, I would like to to ensure all events send to port 5514 are given the type of syslog-network,  which is then filtered by 11-network-filter.conf and send to Elasticsearch logstash-syslog-% index.

At present all the syslog events are falling under the logstash index.

Any ideas why?

**03-network-input.conf**

```
input {
  syslog {
    port => 5514
    type => "syslog-network"
    tags => "syslog-network"
  }
}
```

**11-network-filter.conf**

```
filter {
if [type] == "syslog-network" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp}%{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
}
```

**30-elasticsearch-output.conf**

```
output {
    if "file-beats" in [tags] {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        manage_template => false
        index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
      }
    }

    else if "syslog-network" in [tags] {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "logstash-syslog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      }
    }

    else  {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: are your events even tagged? normally you would use tags => ["syslog-network"] because it is an array

Comment: not sure, do you know how to check?

Comment: you can either use the failure tag ( "_grokparsefailure") to create some parse-failure entries in elasticsearch and take a look at them or you can just start logstash in debug mode ( --log.level debug ) and see what the grok filter is doing